# Cross-compiling [no_std] code - libcore and compiler_builtins not found

Tags: rust, embedded, rust-cargo, bare-metal

I'm trying to follow the steps explained in [Embeddonomicon](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/smallest-no-std.html) to compile the smallest `#![no-std]` program, but for a new target on a new architecture.

1. The architecture is upstreamed in LLVM as an experimental target ("ARC") but its not used by rustc, so first I enabled it in the LLVM that comes with Rust as explained [here](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/building/how-to-build-and-run.html): run `./x.py setup` then update the config.toml:

```
[llvm]
download-ci-llvm = false
ninja = true
targets = "X86"
experimental-targets = "ARC"
```

2. Then I manually added the support for the arch following the steps explained [here](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/compiler-support.html) (using [this commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/52787) as an example):

- created rustc_target/src/abi/call/arc.rs
- updated rustc_llvm/src/lib.rs
- etc

3. Then I added the target file `arc-pc-unknown-gnu.json` and made it visible through `RUST_TARGET_PATH` envvar:

```
{
  "arch": "arc",
  "cpu": "generic",
  "abi": "eabi",
  "c-enum-min-bits": 8,
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-p:32:32-i64:32-f64:32-v64:32-v128:32-a:0:32-n32",
  "eh-frame-header": false,
  "emit-debug-gdb-scripts": false,
  "executables": true,
  "features": "",
  "linker": "rust-lld",
  "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
  "llvm-target": "arc-pc-unknown-gnu",
  "max-atomic-width": 32,
  "atomic-cas": false,
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "relocation-model": "static",
  "target-pointer-width": "32"
}
```

4. Built the compiler: `./x.py build -i --target=arc-pc-unknown-gnu library/core`. It finished successfully, I could see `stage1` libs for the `arc-pc-unknown-gnu` target
5. I thought this would be enough, but the code was not compiling because of the following issues:

```
$ rustc --emit=llvm-ir -o rust_main.ll -C panic=abort --target arc-pc-unknown-gnu src/main.rs
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `arc-pc-unknown-gnu` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add arc-pc-unknown-gnu`
  = help: consider building the standard library from source with `cargo build -Zbuild-std`

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `compiler_builtins`

error[E0412]: cannot find type `PanicInfo` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:18:18
```

This is weird because on the previous step I should have compiled these very libs for my target...

6. Then I though that perhaps I needed to rebuild libcore again using `cargo build-std` (although I don't know why exactly, but someone on the web mentioned this)? I tried this, but now there are the following errors:

```
$ cargo build -Z build-std=core --target arc-pc-unknown-gnu
   Compiling compiler_builtins v0.1.70
   Compiling core v0.0.0 (/home/valeriyk/proj/rust-arc/1.60.0/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage1/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core)
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`

error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope
  --> /home/valeriyk/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/compiler_builtins-0.1.70/build.rs:88:9
   |
88 |         println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=kernel_user_helpers")
   |         ^^^^^^^

error: cannot find macro `println` in this scope
  --> /home/valeriyk/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/compiler_builtins-0.1.70/build.rs:78:9
   |
78 |         println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=thumb_1")
   |         ^^^^^^^
...
```

How come that `libcore` needs `std`? I just want to have it cross-compiled using the stage1 rustc, and then picked up during my #![no_std] example compilation. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: It's not core that needs libstd, it's the build.rs for compiler_builtins that does. Not sure what's going on though, because cargo shouldn't be trying to build libstd for the build script. You can try explicitly depending on compiler_builtins from crates.io rather than via build-std and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I solved the issue:

1. Use the right rustc source code. I started with a stable version whose libcore was not compatible with the latest `compiler_builtins`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72273469/does-cargo-always-use-the-latest-compiler-builtins) for more details. Then I needed to upgrade to the latest nightly.
2. When building the compiler, don't ask to build libcore for the final stage, instead build rustc only:

```
$ ./x.py build -i --stage=1 --target=arcv2-none-elf32 compiler/rustc
```

3. Use the following for the `.cargo/config.toml`, don't use `Xargo` or `-Z build-std=core`. The `compiler-builtins-mem` thing is explained [here](https://blog.knoldus.com/os-in-rust-building-kernel-for-custom-target-part-4/).

```
[unstable]
build-std = [
    "core",
    "compiler_builtins"
]
build-std-features = ["compiler-builtins-mem"]

[build]
target = "arcv2-none-elf32"
```

4. Build the code with a simple `cargo build`. It compiled just fine, although it failed at linking later - but that's another story.